# place random points in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I have created a `JPanel`, and I want my application to create several random points and place them in the panel. I define the size of panel with

```
setBounds(20, 100, 553, 486);
```

I must pay attention to my panel's bounds and only create random points that have *x* and *y* in these bounds. I have created the following code:

```
for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
{
    number=rand.nextInt(300)+100;
    xPoint.add(number);
    yPoint.add(number);
}
```

but my application doesn't work at all. I thought problem may be from this part of my code. Does the above code place points just in the panel? Sorry if my code is too long, but all of its parts are related too each other:

Comment: Define "doesn't work at all".  Do you get an exception?  Unexpected behaviour?  Quits without output?  Your code looks OK for creating a random number between 100 and 399 (inclusive), but based on the `setBounds` call if you're hardcoding `300` and `100` that might cause an out-of-bounds point.

Comment: yes, it cause "NullPointerException" !

Comment: posting all the relevant code, instead of just the bit that is giving you the error will help us more...

Comment: @Sandra: you need to edit your post and show us more of your code. Also, show us the details of the exception.

Comment: Reformatted code; copyedited; please revert if incorrect.

Comment: If the NullPointer exception occurs there will be a stacktrace and the object that is Null, this is relatively easy to track down.

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to place points only on the diagonal of the frame defined by (100, 100,399,399).

I guess that you need something like:

```
int rndX = rand.nextInt(sizeX) + minX;
int rndY = rand.nextInt(sizeY) + minY;
xPoints.add(rndX);
yPoints.add(rndY);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get a NullPointerException you should just look at the stacktrace of the exception and see which line is causing you problems. Something in that line will not have been created and is therefore null. Once you identified which object it is, just create it.

If that does not help, update your post with the relevant code. This would be whatever line is causing the problem and as much of the code that creates the involved objects.